# How to set property name and value on csv load?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can one set both the property name and its value loading a tall skinny csv file? 
The csv file would contain only 3 columns, node name (id), property name (p) and property value (v). A node with to properties would therefore correspond to 2 lines.

```
LOAD CSV... row
MERGE (n) WHERE n.Name = row.id
SET n.{row.p} = row.v
```

This syntax doesn't exit it's just to explain what I'd like to do. Is there a way to do such a thing in cypher? That be really useful rather than having to pivot data first.

A file contains definitions for person nodes:

```
Name,Age
A,25
B,34
```

A second file contains properties for specific nodes, one property per line

```
Name,property_name,property_value
A,weight,64
A,height,180
B,hair color,blond
```

I'd like to update nodes A and B and set additional properties based on the second file.

As mentioned below, one possibility is to create (:Data) nodes containing one property each, and link them person nodes

```
CREATE (p) -[:hasProperty]-> (:Data {Name: row.property_name, Value: row.property_value})
```

However, this might not be very efficient and extracting person nodes and properties gets much more complex.

```
MATCH (p:Person) --> (d:Data)
RETURN {name: p.name, age: p.age, property_names: collect(d.Name), property_values: collect(d.Value)}
```

Graal could either be to set property name dynamically on load, or a pivot function to return data properties on nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not assign a property key dynamically from parameters, however since the row is a map, you can set all the row as properties on the node
if it is ok for you :

```
LOAD CSV ... AS row
MERGE (n:Label {Name: row.id})
SET n += row
```

**EDIT**

Based on your edit, for your second file, if you don't have too much different values like weight, height, etc.. you can create a conditional collection, example :

```
LOAD CSV WITH ... AS row
WITH row, CASE row.property_name WHEN weight THEN [1] ELSE [] END as loopW
UNWIND loopW as w
MATCH (p:Person {name: row.Name})
SET p.weight = row.property_value
WITH row, CASE row.property_name WHEN height THEN [1] ELSE [] END as loopH
UNWIND loopH as h
MATCH (p:Person {name: row.Name})
SET p.height = row.property_value
...
```

Comment: I'm not able to try at the moment. Looks interesting. How would you then access the properties in the node? When I tried n = row, I ended up with n.property_name and n.proverty_value as node properties, containing actual property name and value respectively. With n += row would I get an two array of property_name and _value?

Comment: Well if your column header is Name then you would have a property n.Name, same goes for all colum's. += basically updates the properties map where as = will delete other node properties that are not in row

Comment: Tall skinny csv has 3 columns, id, p and v. P can be age, size, height related to node of name id. My guess is that n+=row will over write p and v. My work around was to create property nodes and link them to the node, but hence the problem it the same at the query level (see my other post) if you want to report a node together with its properties held in the property nodes. I'm missing pivot functions actually.

Comment: In the documentation (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-expressions.html) I see the following syntax for a dynamic property: n["prop"], rel[n.city + n.zip], map[coll[0]]. Shouldn't the following work: LOAD CSV WITH... MATCH (n:Person {Name: row.Name}) SET n[row.p] = row.v ?