# failure trying to shorten CASE-based predicate

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This was inspired by these two SO threads:

[Boolean value return from Neo4j cypher query without CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930174/boolean-value-return-from-neo4j-cypher-query-without-case)

[How to set property name and value on csv load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812113/how-to-set-property-name-and-value-on-csv-load/35813496#35813496)

I have a CSV with 3 columns:

first_name,prop_name,prop_value

John,weight,100

Paul,height,200

John,hair_color,blonde

Paul,weight,120

So, there are a number of people, and their properties are randomly scattered across different rows. My goal is to screen the rows and assign all found properties to their holders. For the sake of simplicity, let's focus on the 'weight' property only.

I do know how to make this work the long way:

```
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
    "file:///test.csv" AS line
    WITH line
    MERGE (m:Person {name:line.first_name})
    WITH line, CASE line.prop_name WHEN "weight" THEN [1] ELSE [] END as loopW 
    UNWIND loopW as w
    MATCH (p:Person {name: line.first_name})
    SET p.weight = line.prop_value
```

But then, I tried to replace the CASE line with a shorter version

```
    WITH line, collect(line.prop_name = "weight") as loopW
```

...which resulted in weird behavior, where the created nodes did get their 'weight' keys assigned to, but sometimes with the wrong values. So, I could see something like (:Person {weight:blue})

What would be the right way to get rid of the CASE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that your current usage filters out all lines that don't have "weight" as the prop_name (the UNWIND of an empty collection wipes out all the other lines and they won't get processed).

What you really need is a better way to set dynamically named properties on your nodes so you can avoid the CASE usage completely.

If you can install [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) (please read the instructions at the top for how to modify your neo4j.conf to whitelist the procedures, and pay attention to the version matrix to ensure you get the version that corresponds with your Neo4j version) there is one that is a perfect fit for what you're trying to do: `CALL apoc.create.setProperty( [node,id,ids,nodes], key, value) YIELD node`

Usage would be something like:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
"file:///test.csv" AS line
MERGE (m:Person {name:line.first_name})
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(m, line.prop_name, line.prop_value) YIELD node
RETURN count(distinct m)
```

EDIT

Expanding on what's wrong with the original query:

UNWIND produces rows in a multiplicative way, with respect to the number of elements in the collection. If the collection in the row had 5 elements, the single row would result in 5 rows, one for each element. If the collection was empty, the row would be removed instead, as there wouldn't be any elements in the collection for which to output rows. Because of this, any further `WITH line, CASE ...` lines in the query wouldn't do any good.

Let's analyze the original query, going by the example input csv:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
"file:///test.csv" AS line
WITH line  //redundant, line not needed
MERGE (m:Person {name:line.first_name}) // 4 rows corresponding with 2 nodes
WITH line, CASE line.prop_name WHEN "weight" THEN [1] ELSE [] END as loopW 
// still 4 rows, 2 have [1] as loopW, the other 2 have [] as loopW
UNWIND loopW as w // 2 rows eliminated by unwinding empty collections
MATCH (p:Person {name: line.first_name})
SET p.weight = line.prop_value
// only 2 rows are for 'John,weight,100' and 'Paul,weight,120'
// any further repetitions of WITH line, CASE ... UNWIND for different props will fail and eliminate the remaining 2 rows.
```

Comment: Wrt the wiping out of the other lines.... I intended to add further "WITH line, CASE line.prop_name WHEN " blocks with other properties in addition to "weight" Could you please expand on that point?

Comment: Also, just so that I can learn from my mistakes  - why specifically didn't the collect() syntax work out in my case, please?

Comment: Added more explanation in my answer. It helps, when you're learning, to RETURN output at various points in the query and see what each successive line is doing. Also, try PROFILE ing your query and watch the number of rows increasing and decreasing as the query executes.

Comment: By the way, I have just installed APOC. Sort of, since I only have access to apoc.load.* and apoc.coll.*, even though I have whitelisted and unrestricted apoc.* in the conf file, as well as .trigger and .meta. I am sure, the file locations are right, since before I made the changes, I didn't have access to APOC at all. Double-checked the versions, as well - 3.3.0 for both neo4j and the jar. Sorry if this is off-topic here.

Comment: Ok, fixed the apoc issue; function works as described. Thank you.